# Appcelerator Studio Run Application Get Fatal Error

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium

I am Using Appcelerator Studio On Win 10 when i try to run application 
i get this in Consol

```
"FATAL ERROR: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal"
```

any body can help Plz..

Comment: Are you trying to run Android? What versions do you have to TiSDK/CLI/Alloy and Android?

Comment: Please edit your question will all relevant information you can think of!